# Cannot see accented characters after I open old files with TeXShop 4.44

Tags: accents, texshop

My document, which worked just fine with the older versions of TeXShop, starts like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Note}


\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

After switching to TeXShop 4.44, while at the same upgrading to a new 
16-inch MacBook pro, Italian words like "necessità" (Italian word for "necessity") is seen in the source file as "necessit")… this is really a big deal for the longest file which I have typed in Italian, which is several hundred pages long… so there are really A LOT of such words.

I have already tried to change the settings going to TeXShop->Preferences->Source and selecting all the possible encoding options for European languages, to no avail so far: accents are either never recognises for what they are, but either as strange combinations like "ÂÃ©" or, though they are displayed as normal accented characters, in the pdf resulting from compiling accented characters are turned into weird combinations of special characters.

Does anybody have a hint on how to solve this ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you already try to open the file with a normal texeditor?

Comment: Be careful, make a backup before you try to play around with the file encodings, you can easily end with quite a mess. Try what happens if you remove the `\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}` line.

Comment: First DON'T EDIT THE FILE! Did you get a warning about `unknown encoding' when you opened that file? Have you ever set the default input/font encoding in TeXShop? The default changed from MacOSRoman to Latin9 and now UTF-8 Unicode (with Latin9 the falback) quite a while ago. Please read TeXShop's Help->File Encoding and TeXShop document and see if that information helps.

Comment: The best way to solve this problem is to convert your legacy MacRoman files to UTF-8. You can do this from the Terminal using `iconv -f MAC -t UTF-8 <file>`, assuming the original file uses `applemac` as the input encoding. Then as Ulrike says,  remove that line from the file when you reopen it.  Removing the line without reencoding the file won't solve things.